# Is it possible to create Oracle associative array type outside of a package/procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle Database 10g, is it possible to create an associative array type outside of a package or procedure?  I would like to be able to do this so that I can reference this associative array type in another type.  For example:

```
create type my_type_map is table of varchar2(10) index by varchar2(10);

create type my_other_type as object (   
    id number(15),
    member procedure initialize(p_my_type_map my_type_map)
) not instantiable not final;
```

The error I get is:

```
SQL> create type my_type_map is table of varchar2(20) index by varchar2(10);
  2  /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors;
Errors for TYPE MY_TYPE_MAP:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/21     PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context
SQL>
```

Seems that Oracle considers:

```
index by varchar2(10)
```

to be PL/SQL and doens't allow it in the creation of SQL types.  If Oracle really doesn't allow associative arrays to be defined outside of packages then is there a good alternative?  Is it possible to create types that extend Oracle's Object inside of a package so that all types are defined in the same package?

Thanks,
Jeff

Edit: Corrected code sample, added log, added possible alternative as question.

Comment: When do you get the error? I just created both types above without complaint from oracle, 10gR2. Your example says INDEX BY VARCHAR2, not pls_integer...

Comment: Added more detail and corrections.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot do what you're trying to do, any more than you can create a type to add a BOOLEAN typed variable to an object. The items in an object must contain Oracle types, not PL/SQL types. A bit clunky alternative could be:

```
CREATE TYPE t_aa AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_ua AS OBJECT (ID NUMBER(15)
                                     , MEMBER PROCEDURE initialize(p_aa t_aa)
                                     , MEMBER PROCEDURE initialize(p_aa_i t_aa))
                               NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
```

Store your associated pairs of variables in the two VARRAYs. You will have to know the largest possible size of your arrays.

Comment: Thanks DCookie.  I've decided against using Oracle object types and am going with straight PL/SQL and record types.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Oracle Objects - I don't see the huge benefit, and they're absolutely nonstandard, making your data structures non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Those are PL/SQL types as the error suggests. There's nothing stopping you from declaring them in the public specification of a package, then you can refer to them in any PL/SQL code you need.

Comment: Doesn't look like packages allow object type definitions:

create or replace
package my_package as
  type my_type_map is table of varchar2(10) index by varchar2(10);
   
  type my_other_type as object (   
    id number(15),
    member procedure initialize(p_my_type_map number)
  ) not instantiable not final;
end;
Error(2,1): PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2603]
Error(5,3): PLS-00540: object not supported in this context.
Error(5,3): PL/SQL: Declaration ignored

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think what he is saying is that you should be declaring the object and the pl/sql type apart from each other

Comment: Unfortuantely an object type defined outside of PL/SQL can not reference anything in PL/SQL.

Comment: I presume you mean an "object type defined outside of a PL/SQL package" - what do you mean by it cannot reference anything in PL/SQL?

"Object types and subtypes can be used in PL/SQL procedures and functions in most places where built-in types can appear. The parameters and variables of PL/SQL functions and procedures can be of object types. You can implement the methods associated with object types in PL/SQL. These methods (functions and procedures) reside on the server as part of a user's schema." http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjenv.htm#sthref552

Comment: Yes, that it was I meant.  Thanks for the clarification.  As far as I can tell I was stuck because I couldn't define the associative array type outside of a package and I couldn't define the dependent object type inside of a package.  So I decided to abandon the object type approach altogether and use Oracle record types.